# Find text from h1 and use it to replace foo2 text

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to use jQuery to find the text within H1 then use this to replace the text already in foo2. Example below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Take text from element</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var str = $("h1").text();
    $("#foo2").html(str);
    $("#foo2").replaceWith( str );
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="foo"><div id="foo2">replace with h1</div></div>

<h1>Text I want to take</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
$("#foo2").text($("h1").text());
```

Comment: 2 seconds before you, and identical answers. Nice!

Comment: Actually you did the opposite what was asked. Look closely ;)

Comment: Cheers guys! Always missing the obvious.

Answer (score 6):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
  var str = $("h1").text();
  $("#foo2").html(str);
  $("#foo2").replaceWith( str );
 });
</script>
```

Your code works, just put $(function() { // your code here }); around it.

Comment: Doh! I'm going to opt for the above $("#foo2").text($("h1").text()); suggestion as its a little more elegant :)

Comment: Do this. I just wanted to say that your code is also correct and you just missed some code around ;) I know that the other suggestions are more elegant to use :)

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
$('#foo2').text($('h1').text());
```

And as Jamiec suggested, don't forget to wrap it in `$(document.ready();`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#foo2').text($('h1').text());
});
```

Otherwise it will execute before the DOM has loaded, meaning it will find no content.

Comment: Dont forget to point out that the code needs to be in a `$(document).ready()` too!

Answer (score 0):

The following page may be useful to you:

[Getting the tag value or element content](http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/jquery-how-to-get-the-tag-value-or-element-content/)